# Avoiding boilerplate code due to equivalent constructors

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have an ADT as follows:

```
Prelude> data Bond = FixedRateBond Float Float | FloatingRateBond Float Float
```

I want to do an operation on every value constructors of this ADT as follows:

```
Prelude> let foo :: Bond -> Float
Prelude|     foo (FixedRateBond a b) = a + b
Prelude|     foo (FloatingRateBond a b) = a + b
```

As you can see I have code duplication here; for every value I have `a + b`. I will have more value constructors so this is going to be repeated even more. To me this is code smell, but I don't know how I would refactor it to eliminate the duplicated code. Is there a functional way to avoid this repeated code? This is a trivial example as I have stripped down the real problem to bare essentials to explain the problem.

Comment: Using `Float` is *usually* a mistake. For most purposes, you're more likely to want `Double`. In a financial context, on the other hand, you will sometimes need fixed point instead.

Comment: @dfeuer, yes I know it's just a dummy example to illustrate the main design problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're correct. This is a code smell, and it's actually a very common modelling mistake. All you need to do is just factor the rate-type out. E.g.,

```
data RateType = Fixed | Floating

data Bond = Bond RateType Float Float
```

Then you'll have

```
foo :: Bond -> Float
foo (Bond _ a b) = a + b
```

atop of other benefits like `RateType` now actually being a type, which you can have `Enum` and `Bounded` instances for.

Basically, the rule of thumb here is: if you have multiple constructors implementing the same thing, there must be an enum asking to be factored out.

Comment: In that case you are probably right, but what do you do when you have that + one parameter on on of the constructor.

Comment: @mb14 That probably is a sign that you have another smaller entity wrapped there and you need to decompose more.